# Ajax not working in opencart

Tags: jquery, opencart

I want to use ajax to retireve data. I have posted the code below that i am using. but it is not working. i am getting the first alert but i am not getting the alert that is in $.ajax section.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#submit").click(function(){ 
     var dd=document.getElementById("url").value;
        alert("hi");

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'test.php?webinarid='+dd,
    success:function(data){
    alert("hi");
}

}); 

     })
      });  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the error event handler to verify that it is not returning successfully and see what is being returned:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'test.php?webinarid='+dd,
    success:function(data){
    alert("hi");
    },
    error:function(data){
    alert("error: " + data);
   }
});
```

you may also use something like firebug to see what is being sent and what is being returned

you should also test the ajax target directly, by opening in your browser

domain.com/test.php?webinarid=01 or whatever ID you care expecting

Comment: if directly accessing the hard-coded URL works, then your javascript is not capturing the url value

replace the first alert with

`alert("dd value:" + dd)` to ensure you are capturing the right variable

Comment: I tried to use error event handler it alert: error: [object Object].
what does it means. also i used my code without opencart and it is working fine but in opencart it is not working.

Comment: where are you putting this code in Opencart and what is the full path to the link it is requesting data from? Try using a full path starting with `http://domain.com/test.php?webinarid=01` and confirm if it still functions fine.

Comment: my tpl file is in \\192.168.1.21\xampp\htdocs\opencart1\upload\admin\view\template\module and php file where the code is supposed to get data is also in the same folder. I have also used the full path but still not working